# Freeform submission only works if 'devMode' => true

Tags: plugin-freeform, craft2, solspace, freeform

I have a locally running form via Solspace's Freeform plugin (Craft2) which perfectly runs on my local setup, but fails silently without any logs or messages on my live-setup.

The form is submitting and saving entries only **if dev-mode is true?**

**Update 1:**
.dev (with dev-mode true) --> works
.com (with dev-mode true) --> works
.dev (with dev-mode false) --> doesnt work
.com (with dev-mode false) --> doesnt work

**Update 2:**
After clicking on submit the document transforms to POST but the URL is not getting changed nor does one get redirected to set returnUrl.

**Update 3:**
Without changing anything I got it to accept data three times. Not reproduceable.

**Update 4**
Because I've read a lot about interfering of .htaccess-rewrites & post method, here is my current .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.222\.333\.44$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: solspace has good support in the craft cms discord group, you might want to @ or ping them with this question.